# Attach binary file with resource on gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, resources, ld

Well, I have a C ++ project, in which I use GCC + MinGW to compile that works perfectly.
But I need to attach a binary file to my output file and I'm trying to do this per resource, but when I try to compile, it gives the following error:

> `C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/…/ld.exe: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file ‘…\resources.res’ is incompatible with i386 output`

Here is the file code resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"

IDR_FILE BIN DISCARDABLE "../bin/File.dll"
```

Here is the code for the resource.h file

```
#define IDR_FILE 541
```

I tried the same thing in VC++ 2015 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: How are you compiling the resource.rc for MinGW?

Comment: I am using the codeblocks as IDE, and as resource compiler the windres.exe

Here is the build log: https://pastebin.com/iJEmHZVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the build log it seems that the resource is built in 64-bit mode (`ld.exe: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file '..\Files\User\resources.res'`), but you are compiling the executable in 32-bit (the "`-m32`" option). Then it cannot link both together because of the mismatch.

Supposed that the dll is 64-bit, try to switch the compiler to 64-bit (use the "-m64" flag, not sure how exactly to switch it in CodeBlocks). Otherwise you would have to switch the windres to 32-bit (possibly by "--target=pe-i386", see here: [TDM-GCC w64 script to change windres for 32bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805155/tdm-gcc-w64-script-to-change-windres-for-32bit)).